# How to parse a cookie file in beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

My organization needs me to authenticate a two factor authentication to scrape an internal website. Every time when i open a browser it will ask for an authentication . The authentication cookie is stored in `c://users//.way//cookie.bat` . I want to use this cookie file to scrape an internal website . can some one help me in this?

sample program

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
header={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}
cookie=c://users//.way//cookie.bat # cookie variable should read the contents in the cookie file and pass it      in requests
source=requests.get('https://www.internalwebsite.com',headers=header,cookie=cookies)
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

### general scraping
```

I tried reading the cookie file but i am unable to do that. kindly help me in reading the cookie file and pass it in requests so that i can access internal website through `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: What are the contents of `cookie.bat`?

Comment: i don't think you can access cookie file directly because they are encrypted so you will need to access the cookies from inspect and network tab of your browser, copy that and use in your request

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup will not handle cookies, instead it's requests job. Automatically parsing cookies from a file and adding them to your request session is going to be a bit a complicated but the general idea would be:

- read the contents of the file with `open`
- parse the file to a python dict (this depends on the format of your cookies file)
- create a [request session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) with your cookies.
- use the session to get the website.

It might be easier to just hardcode the authentication cookies in your code ( `session.auth = ('user', 'pass')` ) if you don't need to update them too often.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is just a ";" separated string in key=value format. You can use Python's built-in [SimpleCookie](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html).

```py
from Cookie import SimpleCookie

cookie = SimpleCookie(<cookie.bat-contents>)
cookies = {k: v.value for k, v in cookie.iteritems()}
requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
```